# Subtract two datasets to display the difference heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, kdeplot

How can I subtract two different kdeplots, so that the difference is displayed? Like in the picture on the top right, there is a green bubble which is overlapping the red one. Is it possible to subtract both datasets from each other and then display the difference? Like when the green dataset is larger than the red one on this specific spot, then the location is green.

My code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import seaborn as sns
from functions.getMinimapExtent import getMinimapExtent
from functions.getMinimapPath import getMinimapPath

def getHeatmap(x, y, map:str, title:str, x1, y1):
    #x ~= [2054, 4225, 4234, 2134, 3552, 5632, ...]
    #y ~= [1452, 2354, 6423, 3256, 2341, 5532, ...]
    #x1 ~= [5323, 2535, 1535, 6433, 2356, 2353, ...]
    #y1 ~= [6435, 2212, 3555, 2366, 7312, 1643, ...]

    img = Image.open(getMinimapPath(map))
    minimapExtent = getMinimapExtent(map)
    plt.imshow(img, extent=minimapExtent)

    # set seaborn style
    sns.set_style("white")

    # Custom the color, add shade and bandwidth
    sns.kdeplot(x=x, y=y, cmap="Reds", shade=True, bw_adjust=.2, alpha=.6, thresh=0.25, zorder=-1)
    sns.kdeplot(x=x1, y=y1, cmap="Greens", shade=True, bw_adjust=.2, alpha=.6, thresh=0.25, zorder=-1)

    plt.title(title)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.savefig("bot/data/img/heatmap.png", dpi=500, bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.close()
```

[image: Seaborn Heatmap]

Comment: Although you have provided much of the relevant information, I feel like I'm missing the actual datasets that you map or pass to `getHeatmap()`. If you could show how the data, coordinates, etc. look like, then we'd be able to get our heads around it.

Comment: @NikitaShabankin x is just the x coordinates and y the y coordinates. its an array